# Is this makefile cache trick safe?

Tags: makefile, build, gnu-make

In my build system, I would like to avoid rebuilding a subproject if none of its files changed. The basic idea is this:

1. After doing `make all`, I hash the contents of the directory and save it.
2. The next time I want to build the project, hash the contents of the directory again.
3. If the hashes are equal, we are done. Otherwise, go to 1.

I'm trying to implement this in GNU Make, using this helper script named `update-hash`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
HASH_FILE=$1
SRC_DIR=$2

echo Hashing sources
UPDATED_HASH=$(tar c $SRC_DIR | sha256sum | cut -c-64)
SAVED_HASH=$(<$HASH_FILE)
if [[ $SAVED_HASH != $UPDATED_HASH ]]; then
    echo "Updating hash"
    echo $UPDATED_HASH > $HASH_FILE
else
    echo "$HASH_FILE is up to date. Not touching it."
fi
```

Here's the tricky part: since Make relies on file modification times to decide what to build, I use two files, `pre_hash` and `post_hash`, and take advantage of the fact that my `update-hash` script does not update the file if the hashes match.

```
subproject: update_pre_hash post_hash

post_hash: pre_hash
        make -C subproject clean all
        update-hash pre_hash subproject
        cp pre_hash post_hash

update_pre_hash:
        update-hash pre_hash subproject
```

The way this works is like this:

- On the first run of `make subproject`, the `pre_hash` file gets updated, and so the `post_hash` rule gets built, ending with a built subproject and with a `post_hash` file that is newer than `pre_hash`.
- On subsequent runs, `update_pre_hash` always gets invoked, but doesn't update the `pre_hash` file, and so the `post_hash` rule does not get invoked.
- If any file in the subproject changes, the `pre_hash` file gets updated, and so `post_hash` gets invoked, resulting in a full build and new hash files.

My question is: will this actually work? Some basic testing did not reveal any glaring problems, but it seems a little shaky. I'm particularly worried about relying on the dependencies of `subproject` getting evaluated in order, which I know is an invalid assumption with `make -j`, but maybe there's a way to fix that.

- Do you see a problem with this implementation?
- If you do, can you suggest any fixes?
- Do you know of another (maybe better) way to achieve the same effect? (other than the obvious "fix the subproject to no-op if there are no changes" - I don't want to maintain the subproject's build process)

---

**Update**: @dash-o suggested a much simpler approach, with a Makefile like this:

```
last_update: $(shell find subproject -type f)
        make -C subproject clean all
        touch last_update
```

This way, `last_update` is always newer than all the files in subproject, but if any files change later, a rebulid will be triggered. Thanks!

Comment: The first time you run it, doesn't it complain that it doesn't know how to build `pre_hash`?

Comment: I've been using similar approach to skip large builds, did not experience issue with the explicit touching of files.

Comment: You want to review 'UPDATED_HASH' - it uses `tar c folder`, which means that you do not control order of hashing files. Consider naming the files with wild-card (which will provide name based sorting), or explicit sort of file name.

Comment: As an alternative, consider creating a 'last-update' file, which will depends on ALL files (with a rule of `touch  $@`) . You can check the timestamp of the 'last-update' as a proxy. Is there a reason that the files timestamp will be updated spontaneously ?

Comment: @Beta For simplicity, I didn't include the part of `update-hash` that deals with a missing hash file, but other than that, `make` didn't seem to mind. I did have that exact problem trying to convert this into pattern rules.

Comment: Your fundamental problem is recursive make. If you can make it non-recursive that would be the ideal. See legendary [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf) for full details.

Comment: Just as a reminder: you should never use raw `make` to invoke sub-makes.  Always, always use `$(MAKE)` (or `${MAKE}` if that's your jam).

Comment: I wonder what's the point? Make itself should not do anything if none of the files have changed, so why not just call make?

Comment: @raspy because the subproject's makefile is poorly written, and will perform a rebuild even if none of the files have changed.